# FieldType of custom WFFM field disappearing

Tags: wffm, fieldtype, custom-field

I'm working on a custom field type for WFFM forms that records a cookie. Our save action uses the `ControlResult`'s `FieldType` property to know when it's a field of this type and do some extra logic on it. The property is added during the control's `GetResult` method, which looks like this:

```
public override ControlResult GetResult()
{
    ControlResult result = new ControlResult(this.FieldItemId, this.Name, (object) this.Value, this.ResultParameters, false)
    {
        FieldType = FieldType
    };

    return result;
}
```

We have a custom save action (`CustomSendEmail`, which implements `ISaveAction`) that reads the control results as an `AdaptedResultList` in its `Execute` method:

```
public void Execute(ID formId, AdaptedResultList adaptedFields, ActionCallContext actionCallContext = null, params object[] data)
```

When I try to debug I observe two things:

1. My custom `GetResult` methods runs as expected, and I can observe the `FieldType` property set on the result before it returns.
2. By the beginning of the `Execute` method, the control result still exists but the `FieldType` is now `null`.

**What step am I missing for my `FieldType` to survive into the save action?**

Relevant details:

- Sitecore 8.1 update 3
- WFFM version consistent with Sitecore version
- Glass Mapper and Castle Windsor (although I don't think they affect anything here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I think I may have figured this out. The `ControlResult` get passed in to an `AdaptedControlResult` before making it to the `Execute` method's `AdaptedControlList` parameter. The constructor for `AdaptedControlResult` sets all of the parameters *except* `FieldType`, which it ignores:

```
public AdaptedControlResult(ControlResult result, IFieldProvider fieldProvider, bool simpleAdapt = false)
{
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) result, "result");
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) fieldProvider, "fieldProvider");
    this.FieldName = result.FieldName;
    this.Parameters = result.Parameters;
    this.FieldID = result.FieldID;
    this.Secure = result.Secure;
    ID result1;
    if (!ID.TryParse(result.FieldID, out result1))
    result1 = ID.Null;
    this.Value = simpleAdapt ? (result.Value ?? (object) string.Empty).ToString() : fieldProvider.GetAdaptedResult(result1, result.Value);
}
```

So there's no way to have that persist. Guess I'll have to use `Parameters` instead.

Comment: Mike, it's ok to post answer to your own question. But its a good practice to also accept the answer if that resolve the problem you were facing. :-)